# cant install android studio on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: android, macos, ide, installation

iam a newbie programmer and i want to learn about the android programming using Android Studio SDK.
But here i problem when installing Android Studio on my Yosemite, it doesn't appear any error report. Like ussual, i download the installer from Android.com, and mount the .dmg file, after that i move the android studio installer to the application folder like the instruction there. But, when i click the android studio icon on launchpad, it just appear warning from gatekeeper, then i allowed (click open) but after that doesn't happen anything. The app (maybe installer) just disappear.
Please gimme a simple answer. Thank You.

Comment: Did you try to go to `System Preferences` and then `Security & Privacy` to see if it was blocked because the developer was not an Identified developer?

Comment: i have did that things, i have already set it to Anywhere source installation

Comment: I've done it without any problem. Maybe is a problem of your System but it would be difficult to answer from here. It is absolutely possible!